# = operator in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, graph, operator-overloading

I'm writing a graph program, and there is a place where I need to check whether the end node of a edge is equal to a node

```
Public Function isAdjacent(ByRef n As node) As Boolean
  For Each edge In edges
    If ((edge.endNode = n) Or ((Not edge.isDirected) AndAlso edge.startNode = n)) Then
      Return True
    End If
  Next
  Return False
End Function
```

`edges` is a [hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). An error is shown under `edge.endNode = n` and `edge.start = n` that says

> operator '=' is not defined for types 'node' and 'node'.

Do I need to overload the [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method? If so, will I not also need to overload the GetHashCode method which I don't really want to do, or is there an easier way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want to check reference equality?

Comment: Yeah, the article posted below showed me how to do it and its working correctly (at least on a quick test)

Comment: By the way, using `ByRef` on the parameter seems wrong since `n` is never assigned a new value inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for reference equality use the `Is` keyword instead.

```
If ((edge.endNode Is n)
```

If not you need to override `Equals` (and I highly recommend to also override `GetHashCode`)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will have to overload the Equals-method. [**This article**](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Equality-Overloading-DotNET) about equality overriding in .NET explains in detail how this is done. Hope this helps.